# Lasker-Noether Theorem and Kummer-Dedekind

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, math-history

I would like to know about the relations between Ernst Kummer's invention of complex ideal numbers (and Dedekind's development of them into what is now called ideals) regarding the unique factorization of an integer into primes and the Lasker-Noether Theorem on factorization, which apparently refers to (polynomial) rings. Is the latter just a special case of the former? In which case do they structurally relate to each other? Are there historical connections between them both?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The modern formulation of the Lasker-Noether theorem applies to all Noetherian rings. By "factorization of an integer into primes" you must mean "factorization of ideals into prime ideals"?

Comment: @rschwieb what does tha mean for its relations with Kummer-Dedekind ideals?

Comment: are you referring to factorization of ideals in dedekind domains?

Comment: Yes. To the invention or development of ideals as a way to get around te problems of non-unique factorization in some cases including complex numbers as parte of the factors and so on.....

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect one to be a special case of the other. They describe ideals in distinct ways. One is products of powers of prime ideals, one is intersections of powers of primary ideals. In Noetherian rings, it is not always the case that intersections and products coincide.

Comment: @rschwieb So is there no relation between both senses of the term?

Comment: Maybe not "no relation" but it's certainly not a straightforward "one is a special case of the other." Perhaps in Dedekind domains the two coincide, but I don't know offhand.

Comment: @rschwieb. Ok, I will ask you in a different manner: Given that Kummer and later Dedekind had already developed ideals, which was the specific motivation for Lasker and then Noether? In other words, which conceptual need was the new concept meant to cover?

Comment: I understand that, but I don't know the history you're seeking. I was just commenting on the two statements.

Comment: @rschwieb I have just seen in your profile (among your interest) that you like to prove that something is not an integral domain.....Are you interested in, say, applications of that issue to other disciplines? As a linguist, I am deeply interested in those problems as they pertain factorization into primitive elements..... I assumme you are German, so feel free to write me in your language, if you like....

Comment: I maintain that list of frequently duplicated questions as an aid for myself on this site. It does not really belong to the list of interests. I'm American born and bred, and you can only get English and Mandarin out of me in terms of language. I am not very familiar with applications of factorization to other disciplines, but that sounds potentially interesting. Regards

Comment: I am trying to figure out the applications to linguistics,or rather, the hidden path that Zelllig Harris and Noam Choamsy took in that regard....